# Why does the code run a command, even if its if statement isn't fulfilled?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, onclick

When I run my code in debug mode, I can see, that for the value "ooy" another content is set (and it would be correct like this) than for the value "skii". But the code still starts the Activity "Game.class", and the Activity "Tutorial.class" too but only in background. How can I solve this?

MainScreen:

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile1";
    String ooy;
    String skii;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

        SharedPreferences tutoask = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        ooy = tutoask.getString("skipMessage", "NOT checked");

        skii = "checked";

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();
            if (id == R.id.btn_start) {

                startActivity(new Intent(this, Tutorial.class));

                if (ooy.equals(skii)){
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, Game.class));
                }
            }
```

Tutorial:

```
public class Tutorial extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {

    Button btn;
    public CheckBox checkBox1;
    String checkBoxResult = "NOT checked";
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile1";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorial);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startut);
        btn.setOnClickListener( this);
        checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (checkBox1.isChecked()){

            checkBoxResult = "checked";

            SharedPreferences tutoask = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = tutoask.edit();
            editor.putString("skipMessage", checkBoxResult);

            // Commit the edits!
            editor.commit();
        }
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Game.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: then obviously !ooy.equals(skii) is true. what type ooy and skii is, and where it gets a value?

Comment: @Skaros  Updated Question. Sorry, not whole code at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you saying that the two variables have different values? Sorry, your sentence is difficult to understand.

If the variables are not equal it would execute what is inside the `if` command since you have the NOT (!) command.

If they are NOT equal execute the command:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,Game.class));
```

I am not sure what you want to do and what the actual problem is. You have two variables with not equal values; when you check the two, they are not equal, so the command inside the `if` is executed. As it should since you have the not statement.

Comment: If the user comes new into the app, the tutorial shows up. if he clicks "dont show this again" which should set the "ooy" equal to "skii", it should skip the tutorial every time and bring him directly to the game.

Comment: well now I deleted the ! . but still not working. It just ignores if i check the "do not show again" checkbox

Comment: What are the values of the two variables?

Comment: It's fine, it just didn't refreshed the shared preferences on the main page when I closed the game.class, but now it's working as I'm setting the shared preferences in onResume..

Answer (score 0):

Look at the equals method of the ooy and skii objects. They are probably implementhed wrong.